# How to find the expected cost of an exponential probability?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-function

The length $X$ of of a call follows the exponential distribution with mean $2$ minutes. In dollars, the cost of of a call of $x$ minutes is $3x^2-6x+2$. Find the expected cost of a call?

The addition of the $3x^2-6x+2$ is what is throwing me off, as I know to find $E(x)$ of exponential distributions is just $\dfrac{1}{\lambda}$, meaning the rate $\lambda$ is equal to $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Any help on solving this is helpful!

Comment: If your call is 1 minute long, you *receive* 1 dollar? Cool.

Comment: Do you know how to find the expectation of $3X^2-6X+2$?

Comment: An integral right? from 0 to infinite?

Comment: Use the fact that expectation is linear: $\mathbb E(3X^2-6X+2)=3\mathbb EX^2-6\mathbb EX+2$. It remains to find $\mathbb EX^2$ and $\mathbb EX$. The second of these was allready mentioned in your question.

Comment: Ok... I'm lost. How does this relate to an exponential distribution then?

Comment: $X$ is exponentially distributed and if $C$ denotes the cost then $C=3X^2-6X+2$  wich is an expression in $X$. Finding $\mathbb EC$ (the expected cost of a call) is the same as finding $\mathbb E(3X^2-6X+2)$

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm just not following. How am I supposed to find (3X2−6X+2)? Is that a distribution?

Answer (score 0):

To find the expected value of something, you multiply each of its values by the probability of those values, and add them all up, which in this case means you integrate.
$$E(3X^2 - 6X + 2) = \int_0^{\infty} (3x^2 - 6x + 2)f(x)dx$$
where f(x) is the pdf of the exponential distribution, so
$$E(3X^2 - 6X + 2) = \int_0^{\infty} (3x^2 - 6x + 2)\frac{1}{2}e^{-x/2}dx.$$
Note that "the probability of those values" here means $f(x)dx$ = $e^{-x/2}dx$ which becomes a probability of a cost in some interval when we integrate. It's not $f(x) = e^{-x/2}$ itself.  But you don't have to integrate all of of that because
$$E(3X^2 - 6X + 2) = E(3X^2) - E(6X) + 2$$
$$= 3E(X^2) - 6E(X) + 2.$$
You already know $E(X) = 2$, so you just need $E(X^2)$, so find that like above.
$$E(X^2) =  \int_0^{\infty} x^2\frac{1}{2}e^{-x/2}dx$$